# Qt Qmenu set layout direction to right does not work

Tags: qt, right-to-left, qmenubar

In Qt I use a `QMenuBar` and  add some menus to it. My program is multi language and when I use a left to right language like English, every thing is OK, and when I choose a language which has right to left direction, I have to add this line to my main.cpp:

```
MainWindow w;
w.setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
```

So every widgets move to right except `QMenubar`.

I also add this line to my `QMenuBar`:

```
ui->menubar->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
```

and

```
QApplication::setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
```

But nothing happens.

Should I set/change another option?

Answer (score 0):

It helped me to override QMenu::item and QMenu::item:selected styles, for example

```
settingsList->setStyleSheet("QMenu::item { background-color: white; } QMenu::item:selected { background-color: blue; }");
settingsList->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
```

Comment: Perhaps this is because I have a MainWindow object exhibited a property of the layout direction right to left